# Moniter data Usage for Specific WiFi Network (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, network-monitor

I have a metered internet connection at home and am looking to track my data usage on my Windows 10 laptop similarly to the windows 10 data usage tracker, but for this specific WiFi network (or all networks set to metered) rather than all WiFi connections. Is there any software that does this?

NOTE: I do not want something that monitors all connections together.  I want something that monitors a specific network.

Edit for clarification: I want a piece of windows software to track the total data transfer over a specific WiFi Network.

Comment: Please clarify. For example I can interpret this as:   A) Monitor TCP/UDP/etc connections on Win machine that are generating traffic on IP network X (WLAN)   , or: B) WLAN GW reports it's connection stats via SNMP/UI/other to the Win machine.

Comment: Do you mean a specific SSID?

Comment: Yes @Mawg (eg. MyMeteredSSID but not UniversitySSID)

Answer (score 1):

So what you're asking for is something to monitor a **single network interface card** (your WiFI in this instance) on your PC. First and foremost, would the `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` not work for session based viewing:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterStatistics

Name                             ReceivedBytes ReceivedUnicastPackets       SentBytes SentUnicastPackets
----                             ------------- ----------------------       --------- ------------------
Ethernet 2                          5399113933                  81994       360739612            3270272
```

This `cmdlet` can be accessed via PowerShell (standard on newer operating systems), and does not require any additional configuration.

Comment: I want to moniter a specific WiFi **Network**, not a card.